# Write FDF to PDF using iTextsharp

Tags: pdf, itext, fdf

I am trying to save a **PDF** file by saving the data from the **FDF** into a **PDFTemplate**, in my **WPF** application.

So, the situation is like this. I have a **PDFTemplate.pdf** which serves as a template and has placeholders (or fields). Now I generate this **FDF** file pro-grammatically, which in turn contain all the field names required for the **PDFTemplate** to be filled in. Also, this **FDF** contains the file path for the **PDFTemaplte** also, so that on opening, it knows which **PDF** to use.

Now, when try and double click on the **FDF**, it open the **Adober Acrobat Reader** and displays the **PDFTemplate** with the data filled in. But I can't save this file using the File menu, as it says this file will be saved without the data.

So, then I decide to use **iTextsharp**, read the **PDFTemaplate** file, read the **FDF** file and get the data from there, and create another **PDF** file and save it along with the data.

The following is the code that I am using but when I open the newly saved file, it says that the file is damaged and could not be repaired:

```
    using (MemoryStream pdfFlat = new MemoryStream())
    using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(templateLocation))
    using(PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, pdfFlat))
    using(FdfReader fdfReader = new FdfReader(fdfFileNameAndPath))
    {
        AcroFields pdfForm = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
        pdfForm.SetFields(fdfReader);
        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
        pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;

        using (FileStream saveStream = 
            new FileStream(
                outputFileNameAndPath, 
                FileMode.Create, 
                FileAccess.Write))
        {
            pdfFlat.WriteTo(saveStream);
            pdfFlat.Flush();
            saveStream.Close();
        }

        fdfReader.Close();
        pdfStamper.Close();
        pdfReader.Close();
        pdfFlat.Close();
    }
```

I am not sure as to what am I doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: Late to the party, but I think you only needed to reset the MemoryStream position to 0 before flushing to file stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it by not using the ***MemoryStream***:

```
  File.Copy(formLocation, outputFileNameAndPath, true);

  using (FileStream pdfFlat = new FileStream(outputFileNameAndPath,FileMode.Open))
  using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(formLocation))
  using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, pdfFlat))
  using (FdfReader fdfReader = new FdfReader(fdfFileNameAndPath))
  {
      AcroFields pdfForm = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

      pdfForm.SetFields(fdfReader);
      pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
      pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;

      fdfReader.Close();
      pdfStamper.Close();
      pdfReader.Close();
      pdfFlat.Close();
  }
```

I am not sure but when I was using the ***MemoryStream*** to open the file and then save it into another ***FileStream***, something was not working, not sure what.

But I tried to make it simpler and it worked.

Comment: What do you mean by annot fdf files? fdf files are just text files.

Comment: collection of comments (which is extracted from one pdf) and saved as fdf files. I try to import this fdf file to new pdf. (http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/131-marking-up-and-adding-comments-to-pdf-documents)

Comment: My fdf files contains <annot> instead of <field>. When I try to load my ftf files via fdfreader its having null values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar example using memory stream instead of file stream.  I believe you only needed to set the memory stream position to 0.  I also get the pdf template file name from the fdf FileSpec property which is helpful if you have several possible templates.

```
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
using (FdfReader fdfReader = new FdfReader(fdfFilePath))
using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fdfReader.FileSpec))
using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, stream)) {
    AcroFields pdfForm = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
    pdfForm.SetFields(fdfReader);
    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
    pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;

    fdfReader.Close();
    pdfStamper.Close();
    pdfReader.Close();

    stream.Position = 0;
    //string contentType = "application/pdf";
    //SaveStreamToCloudStorage(contentType, stream, cloudStorageFileName);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to import annotation fdf to pdf?