# how to display submitted form data from PDF in browser

Tags: java, itext

I've generated a PDF using iText with form fields and a submit button that POSTS the data as FDF. I dedcided to use POST instead of GET because of the size of data that needs to be submitted. I would like the client to open this PDF in the standalone Acrobat Reader application. In the servlet, I can read in the streamed data. My problem now is, how would I display the streamed data on a webpage?

I searched SO and it looks like a similar question was asked here:
[Sending 'success' response back to Acrobat Reader from java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862698/sending-success-response-back-to-acrobat-reader-from-java-servlet)

Reading Bruno's answer, it looks like my only option is #2 but unsure of how I would stream the form's data to the server, and then back a webpage to display.

Thanks for the any help, input or suggestions!

Comment: I don't think you can do this. You have no way of knowing whether the user even has an open browser. Where would you stream the response to? Most browsers only display responses to requests they themselves made. You would have to have the PDF open a browser, then tell the browser to make a request to your server, so that you can reply with your content.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say you are unsure of how you would stream the forms data to the server, but... you've already solved that part: you **post** the data to the server as FDF. On the server, you do two things with the FDF: (1) you store it because data collection is why you ask the user to fill out the form in the first place, (2) you merge the data with the original form and you send that form back to the client through the response object. Knowing this, what is the question?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insights Joao. Bruno, sorry for being unclear. Yes I've posted the data to the server. My question is more on sending a response back to the client. What I'm looking to achieve is; 1) user submits form with data to server, 2) server manipulates data, 3) sends response back and then displays the manipulated data on a webpage. I've completed steps 1 and 2 but unsure on how to approach step 3.

Comment: If you want the end user to be able to open the file in a stand alone Adobe Reader, then (1) you should return a PDF file, and (2) force the file to be opened externally by changing the Content-Disposition. This question has been answered many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, we were able to establish that you are asking two simple things.

1. You are trying to merge an FDF file with its original form. This is done using the `FdfReader` class in combination with "traditional" form filling: [Write FDF to PDF using iTextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273610/write-fdf-to-pdf-using-itextsharp)
2. You want to return the result to the end-user and have him open it in Adobe Reader: [Read PDF file and offer it as download with iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433228/read-pdf-file-and-offer-it-as-download-with-itext)

I realize that this answer doesn't conform with the rules on StackOverflow, as it is a "link-only" answer. My other options would have been: marking the question as duplicate (but then I'd only be able to pick one of the two answers that need to be combined), or adding my answer as a comment, but then it would look as if the question isn't answered.